# to search people by photo in facebook ( using face recognition )

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, search-engine

I am currently working onto a simple image search engine project (going on similarlity search) . Working onto the project, my partner asked with an concept of search people by photo in facebook . SO , i think implementing these concepts into our project would be quite interesting . This cant be a security issue , since at least profile pictures are public .

So , i am here with a question :: Is there any already available api or web service or any software tool that could return result using facebook face recognition by processing the images on facebook store, if the given input is any image of a particular facebook user (which may not in fb store ).

if possible , i would prefer coding in php ,python or java ...........
Or at least hints are always encouraged!!!

By the way ,never mind on language please!!!

Comment: It's way too broad. And looking for library, service or references are off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: which search engine you are using

Comment: tring by own using some feature extraction tools in python 

using some hints like in :

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/

Answer (score 3):

Some good APIs for Face Recognition and Feature Detection (Mood, Glasses, ...):

- http://skybiometry.com/ (5000 calls/month free)
- http://www.faceplusplus.com/ (currently free)

Answer (score 0):

for any Facebook related. you should have to use Facebook API.

They are providing.

[Check the Facebook Documentation and gone through this.](http://developers.facebook.com/)